# What happens when Expedia has two frequent flier numbers for you for the same alliance?

Tags: airlines, loyalty-programs, expedia, oneworld

British Airways and American Airlines are both part of the Oneworld alliance and I have frequent flier numbers for both of them - for American AAdvantage and British Airways Executive Club. And they're both in Expedia.

So let's say I buy a plane ticket from the United States to Europe. I assume only one frequent flier number gets the miles. But which one?

Comment: I haven’t used Expedia in a couple of decades, but I suppose that when you book, it preselects a FF account, but lets you change it, doesn’t it?

Comment: Aside from @jcaron's comment, you can always change the frequent flyer number when you check in for the flight.  It's ultimately between you and the airlines; the travel agent only plays a secondary role.

Answer (score 5):

When you are entering passenger information during the purchase process, there is a drop-down to select the frequent-flier account for each passenger. It is filled with some default value but you can change it to one of your choosing independently for each passenger. The options are *not* filtered by alliance, so make sure you select one that matches the ticket being purchased.